# hugchat is not remembering my name, integrated with django

Tags: python, django

```
def ChatBotCreateCookie(husername=husername, hsecret=hsecret):
    sign = Login(husername, hsecret)
    cookies = sign.login()
    cookie_path_dir = "./"
    sign.saveCookiesToDir(cookie_path_dir)
    return cookies


def ChatBotVerifyCookie(husername=husername):
    if os.path.exists(f"{husername}.json"):
        cookie = f"{husername}.json"
    else:
        ChatBotCreateCookie()
        cookie = f"{husername}.json"
    return cookie


def ChatBotLogin():
    cookie = ChatBotVerifyCookie()
    chatbot = hugchat.ChatBot(cookie_path=cookie)
    return chatbot


def LandingFunction(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def ChattingRequest(request):
    ChatRequestString = request.GET['ReqText']
    ChatConn = ChatBotLogin()
    ChatResponse = ChatConn.chat(ChatRequestString)
    print("Request="+ChatRequestString+"\nResponse="+str(ChatResponse))
    return HttpResponse(str(ChatResponse))
```

This is my view, i have logged in using cookie but maybe hugchat is not creating a session for my requests.(I have done it with core python using while and it worked fine, how can i do the same here)

I want to create the ChatConn object once and use it for all the requests being made in current session rather than creating again and again on each request.

it could be possible by storing the ChatConn object in session but python does not allow me to do so.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.